# Which web languages can I use to write to disk from a web / browser app?

Tags: web-applications, programming-languages, save

I know that Javascript is incapable of saving data on a users local machine except for browser-oriented things (perhaps someone could enumerate those?).  Which languages *can* write to a user's local machine?

I ask because I want to make a simple note-keeping application to use myself, but I'm not sure how to save the notes I make...

Comment: I haven't looked into how it works, but [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) is a wiki written in Javascript that saves files somewhere locally.

Comment: If you're making a web app, why not just store the notes on the web server?

Comment: Use HTML5 LocalStorage (Javascript).

Comment: @Sam Dufel: I wanted to test a local version first, since I want it to work offline, too.  But eventually, if it's cool, I plan to share it.  Others could also use it while offline.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can write cookies with javascript, if the information you want to store is small enough. Otherwise you'd need some client-side plugin:

- java applet, javaFX
- flash
- silverlight
- activeX
- xul (firefox way of writing plugins)

Comment: It seems like these will all be disabled pretty soon when browsers drop NPAPI. So I think there won't be a way for general saving of data to a user's local machine.

Answer (score 2):

[TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.org/) is written in Javascript and it does indeed write itself to local disk. Check the sources to see how they do it.

http://svn.tiddlywiki.org/Trunk/core/js/FileSystem.js

Answer (score 0):

Flash allows some disk writing (though the client controls how much space is allocated). Also ms active x objects give you this ability, but the end user has to approve the behavior